# Can't connect to specific network interface

Tags: erlang, inet, gen-tcp

i've read docs for **'inet'**, **'gen_tcp'**, but can't understand where is error.

connect_option() = 
    {ip, inet:socket_address()}

socket_address() = 
    ip_address()

ip_address() = ip4_address() | ip6_address()

ip6_address() = 
    {0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535}

so it must be {ip, {0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535,
     0..65535}}

```
(aaa@127.0.0.1)8> Ip = {65152,0,0,0,51840,11332,54567,49336}.
{65152,0,0,0,51840,11332,54567,49336}
(aaa@127.0.0.1)9> gen_tcp:connect({127,0,0,1}, 6653, [binary, {packet, raw}, {active, false}, {ip, Ip}]).
{error,eafnosupport}
(aaa@127.0.0.1)10> gen_tcp:connect({0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, 6653, [binary, {packet, raw}, {active, false}, {ip, Ip}]).
** exception exit: badarg
     in function  gen_tcp:connect/4 (gen_tcp.erl, line 148).

inet:getifaddrs().
{ok,[{"lo",
      [{flags,[up,loopback,running]},
       {hwaddr,[0,0,0,0,0,0]},
       {addr,{127,0,0,1}},
       {netmask,{255,0,0,0}},
       {addr,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}},
       {netmask,{65535,65535,65535,65535,65535,65535,65535,
                 65535}}]},
     {"eth0",
      [{flags,[up,broadcast,running,multicast]},
       {hwaddr,[82,84,0,229,5,188]},
       {addr,{172,17,0,218}},
       {netmask,{255,255,255,128}},
       {broadaddr,{172,17,0,255}},
       {addr,{65152,0,0,0,20564,255,65253,1468}},
       {netmask,{65535,65535,65535,65535,0,0,0,0}}]},
     {"eth1",
      [{flags,[up,broadcast,running,multicast]},
       {hwaddr,[82,84,0,229,5,189]},
       {addr,{65152,0,0,0,51840,11332,54567,49336}},
       {netmask,{65535,65535,65535,65535,0,0,0,0}}]}]}
```

or

```
(aaa@127.0.0.1)9> Op.
[binary,
 {packet,raw},
 {active,false},
 {reuseaddr,true},
 {ip,{65152,0,0,0,51840,11332,54567,49336}}]
(aaa@127.0.0.1)10> gen_tcp:listen(6653, Op).
```

{error,einval}

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [gen_tcp](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html) doc again, you will see that when working with ipv6 address, you need to add the Socket Option **inet6**, which you are missing on your code

Try this code, it should work:

```
Op = [binary, {packet,line}, {active,false}, {reuseaddr,true}, inet6, {ip, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}].
gen_tcp:listen(8000, Op).
```

Comment: ok, but this still gives an error
Op = [binary, {packet,line}, {active,false}, {reuseaddr,true}, inet6, {ip, {65152,0,0,0,51840,11332,54567,49336}}].
{ok, L} = gen_tcp:listen(6653, Op).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,einval}

Comment: f(Op). ? You are trying to assign a variable to different values, like:
A = 1. A = 2. That is the way to get that right hand side value error.